# TestCafe ClientFunction TypeError error as document is undefined

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I can successfully execute the following .click:

```
const clickMockContinueButton = ClientFunction(() => document.getElementsByName("paymentGatewayIframeReturnSubmit")[0].click())
```

by calling it with:

```
await clickMockContinueButton();
```

But even after the successful .click I get a TypeError:

```
An error occurred in ClientFunction code:

TypeError: document.getElementsByName(...)[0] is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

*** EDIT with workaround ***

Seems there is a bug in my mocked page when I use either TC .click(Selector) or document.getElementsByName().click(), in that the action is being performed twice, therefore the 2nd click attempt throws an error because the button doesn't exist anymore.

So I decided to move on and use a simple workaround as:

```
async function handleMockContinueButton() {
    var focus = ClientFunction(() => {
        document.getElementsByName("paymentGatewayIframeReturnSubmit")[0].focus();
    });

    await focus();
    await t.pressKey("enter");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the "`TypeError`" issue with your information. My `test.js`:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `https://google.com/`;

const clickInput = ClientFunction(() => document.getElementsByName('q')[0].click())

test('test', async t => {
    await clickInput(); 
});
```

TestCafe version: `1.3.3`

Command: `testcafe chrome test.js`

Result:

```
Running tests in:
- Chrome 75.0.3770 / Windows 10.0.0

My fixture
√ test


1 passed (3s)
```

I suggest you use [`t.click( selector [, options] )`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/click.html) in your test.

Comment: This issue is occurring since we introduced this mock fix: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2012. 

All click actions on the button are being duplicated, whether I use TC t.click() or document.getElementsByName("element")[0].click(). 

The button is always clicked once and then the second attempt to click throws the error because the button doesn't exist anymore i.e. The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree... with TC t.click()

I've no idea why this is happening within out HTML mocked page or whether it's not related to TestCafe at all!

Comment: I think for now I'll need to figure out how to suppress the error in this scenario.

Comment: catch(e) error log:

{ code: 'E4',
  isTestCafeError: true,
  callsite:
   CallsiteRecord {
     filename:
      '/my-account-payment-cards.js',
     lineNum: 66,
     callsiteFrameIdx: 3,
     stackFrames:
      [ [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        CallSite {},
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite] ],
     isV8Frames: true },
  errMsg: 'TypeError: document.getElementsByName(...)[0] is undefined',
  instantiationCallsiteName: 'ClientFunction',
  isRejectedDriverTask: true }

Comment: If you try to get an element that is in an `<iframe>`, you need to change your test's browsing context from the main window to this `<iframe>` by using the [switchToIframe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/working-with-iframes.html) TestCafe action. Otherwise, the `getElementsByName` method will return empty `NodeList`. Please check if you use the right browsing context.