# How to implement window.onerror with TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, testing, error-handling, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to suppress an error (the error is coming from a mocked page) in my TestCafe test. Example code:

```
function stoperror() {
            try {
                this.clickMockContinueButton();
             } catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
             } 
            return true;
        }

Call it:

window.onerror = stoperror;
```

Although I've added Node window package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/window

Error = ReferenceError: Window is not defined

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe provides only two ways to execute your JavaScript code in browsers: [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#creating-client-functions) and [t.eval](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#one-time-client-code-execution). For example, if you want to install a global error handler via the `window.onerror` property, you can use the following code:

```js
const installErrorHandler = ClientFunction(() => {
   window.onerror = error => {
       // handle error here
   };
});

test('Install the error handler', async t => {
    await installErrorHandler();
});
```

But I should warn you that this method won't work if you warn to suppress an error described in your other question: [TestCafe ClientFunction TypeError error as document is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57327950/testcafe-clientfunction-typeerror-error-as-document-is-undefined)

The error from this question happens in a `ClientFunction` context and can't be propagated to the global error handler. If you want to suppress an error that happens in a `ClientFunction` instance, wrap your code inside its body with the `try ... catch` statement:

```js
const dangerousFunction = ClientFunction(() => {
    try {
        // dangerous code
    }
    catch (e) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey for a detailed response as always from the TestCafe team.